# Differences between "how to do something....." and "how do I do something..."

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography

"how to...." is correct ? or Impolite？
I'm not really make sure What's the difference between the two.

Comment: The first is a statement and the second is a question.

Comment: Give us the whole sentence you want, so we can understand you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As someone already mentioned, "how to do" can only be a part of a statement. For example,

"I don't know how to do it."

So if you intend to ask a person how something should be done, you should say,

"How do I do it?" and not "How to do it?"

This isn't impolite but if you want to be more polite, try

"Could you please tell me how to do it?"

Comment: No; it can be part of a fragment ('How to keep pet fish').

Comment: 'How to keep pet fish' is still a statement.

Comment: No it's not. It doesn't assert anything. It can't be judged true or false (contrast 'this book describes the best ways to keep pet fish').